# Mock IP Address for Remote Mysql Connection .NET C Sharp

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, unit-testing, mocking

Hello wonderful community of stack overflow,

I am recently a .net developer working in c sharp. Right now, I am trying to write a set of unit tests to test the security of a mysql database. Part of the test suite is to make sure that the mysql database can not accept connections from certain ip addresses. I have been trying my best to find a way to test this. By ideas thus far have been:

1. Mock the ip address that I currently have so that the connection I am making thinks its coming from another ip address
2. SSH into a remote server that has one of the unacceptable ip addresses and execute a shell command to make a connection to the mysql server

I have not found a way to manually change the ip address being sent to the mysql server. I am using the MySqlConnection class from the MySql.Data.MySqlClient assembly. As far as my research shows, this is not possible. (which is probably a good thing)

I have learned through research that .Net does not have a native SSH library and pulling in one is not a possibility for this project which has stunted my ability to perform #2.

From this, I am at a loss as to how to continue. Has anyone had any experience in mocking database connections and having control over the origin ip? (or any other information for that matter)?

Any help or resources is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be overkill for that particular task, but the way how I see that.

You need a proxy server, with IP address banned on your MySQL instance.

Then you testing successfull connection, just connect directly from your machine to MySQL (it should connect fine).

Then testing failure scenario, redirect request throught proxy (I hope that MySQLClient allow that, anyway you can create a simple proxy on your own). In this case connection should fail.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Im not sure I can get a proxy server going for this task since, as you said, it may be some overkill. Im also concerned about the security risk that could present? Have you had any experience with that before?

Comment: what security risk as you talking about? i assume everything there is done in local network on some test MySQL database, isn't it? Proxy idea seems to be most feasible in you case, think about it as just a simple application that runs another machine and redirect your request, so the request would "go" from another ip - exactly as you need.

Comment: Id love to be able to say that we are using a local DB but ive been specifically instructed to run all tests on live resources against recommendation. Thanks for your help and advice! I may end up using this and will choose this as the answer